# How to use Dialog.ElicitSlot for Python as Runtime environment

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I want to fill a `slot` not at the beginning of the invocation of the intent, but at a later part in the *intent request*. I want to provide user some options, and I want them to select one out of those. For that I'm trying to use `Dialog.ElicitSlot`, but somehow I'm getting an error :

> "Request to skill endpoint resulted in an error."

I'm returning this when I need the user to select an option from my list.

```
return {
    "version": "1.0",
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "PlainText",
        "text": "These are the multiplex" + ("es" if len(multi_list) > 1 else "") + " " + outputSpeech + ". Please select one out of these."
        # outputSpeech contains the list of options I want the user to select from
    },
    "shouldEndSession": False,
    "directives": [
        {
            "type": "Dialog.ElicitSlot",
            "slotToElicit": "MULTIPLEX",
            "updatedIntent": {
                "name": "GetMovieDetails",
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
                "slots": {
                    "CITY" : {
                        "name" : "CITY",
                        "confirmationStatus" : "NONE",
                        "value" : city # this is already filled, it is just anti-capitalised 
                    },
                    "NAME" : {
                        "name" : "NAME",
                        "confirmationStatus" : "NONE",
                        "value" : movie_name # this is already filled, it is just anti-capitalised 
                    },
                    "MULTIPLEX" : {
                        "name" : "MULTIPLEX",
                        "confirmationStatus" : "NONE",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm testing my skill using `python-lambda-local`, it is working fine on my local machine (I just had to change the `dialogState` to `"COMPLETED"` manually, like the one [here](https://github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/Alexa-Flick/blob/f09014b9886a0d40906a8085f5ee3c1eb1554dd3/events/GetMovieDetails02.json#L76)). It returns everything written above. But It gives an error while testing it on Skill Tester. [Here](https://github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/Alexa-Flick/blob/master/events/errorOutput.json) is the output which is returned in the Skill Tester.
PS : I did not check the Slot Filling check box in the Build Section. (As I need the slot to be filled later), and [here](https://github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/Alexa-Flick/blob/e04e889273f925a904ac964dca19fda1a0163c7b/lambda_function.py#L199) is the complete code just in case.

Comment: If anyone wants, I can award my bounty to them. It'll be wasted otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

God, I hate to admit this.

The `Dialog.ElicitSlot` works fine, and the way I expect it to do so. 
The error with my code is, **there is no error**. I figured my skill was taking some time to fetch data from remote site and doing some calculations on it. So I increased the time out and bam, it worked.

It is always a better to test your skill locally, but it is great to test it once on the *aws lambda console*. I don't know why I didn't do that earlier.

So to conclude, I just had to **increase the timeout** in my skill.

Answer (score 0):

Try with omitting the entire `"updatedIntent"` part, as this information is not required for `ElicitSlot`.

But more important: You have to make sure that your script returns actual text in JSON-format!

Have a look at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.json.jsonify
or https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I want to know, is it even possible to get the slot value at a later part and not in the beginning? when the user has some options to choose from.